# Can we use two Google Cloud Messaging SENDER_ID in one Application?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hii friends i am new to GCM. I have an app where i have to register different user using GCM based on the `category{category1 , category2}`

if user is choosing `Category1` then he will be registered for `Server1` and 
user will receive `notification from Server1`. 
Similarly if user chooses to register for `category2` then user will receive `notification from Server2`.
So, is it possible that i can use two GCM SENDER_ID in an Application. and if yes then what is the what so that i can perform it .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a late reply ;)

You can create a new project and get SENDER_ID from GCM developer console.

And on android side;
You can set SENDER_ID for chosen category as;

```
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID1);
```

or

```
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID2);
```

I hope, this helps people who have been still seeking this question's answer.